# React storing prop value from outcome of loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, semantic-ui-react, semantic-ui-redux-form-fields

Is it possible to store the value of a component prop from the result of a loop in React?

I have the following component:

```
<CheckboxSemantic 
  defaultChecked={questionItem.answer.map((answerItem, answerItemItemIndex) => {
        if (answerItem.value === questionMapping.value) {                                                                                 
          return true;                                                                                
        }
          return false; 
       })
     } />
```

This returns the following error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `defaultChecked` of type
>   `array` supplied to `Checkbox`, expected `boolean`.

Is there a better way I can achieve this?

Comment: The error is probably coming from propTypes.. try changing the type to boolean.

Comment: It's already a boolean prop, the problem is the return of the map function is not returning a Boolean

Comment: Do you need it to be an array? It feels like you could use Array.prototype.every or something similar to check if all the answers are true or false or in other way... make it accept always an array in proptypes if you are passing a map. And then a defaultProp of [] for defaultChecked.... But it feels for me that you are doing something weird in your component.

Comment: No I don't want tit to be an array. I am basically setting the checkbox `checked` dynamically. in order for me to do that I need to loop over some array. So I want it to return a boolean not an array.

Comment: If you want to return multiple checkboxes, you should do `questionItem.answer.map((item, idx) => <CheckboxSemantic key={idx} defaultChecked={item.value===questionMapping.value} />)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies at `map`. It will always return an `array`. You need to use `reduce` like below.

```
<CheckboxSemantic 
  defaultChecked={questionItem.answer.reduce((acc, answerItem) => {
        if (answerItem.value === questionMapping.value) {                                                                                 
          acc = true;                                                                                
        }
        return acc; 
       }, false)
     } />
```

Note: Not tested, expect syntax error.

Comment: This works! Thanks.. forgot about reduce. I'll accept when it lets me.